# c++ unresolved external symbol when trying to compile program

Tags: c++

When trying to compile my program this error shows up:

```
Error   1   error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: static class sf::Texture TextureManager::texture" (?texture@TextureManager@@2VTexture@sf@@A)
```

This is my code:

**main.cpp:**

```
int main()
{
     TextureManager::Initialize();
}
```

**TextureManager.h:**

```
#include <SFML\Graphics.hpp>
using namespace sf;

class TextureManager
{
    public:
        static Texture texture;
    public:
        static void Initialize();
};
```

**TextureManager.cpp:**

```
#include <SFML\Graphics.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include "TextureManager.h"

using namespace sf;

void TextureManager::Initialize()
{
    if(!texture.loadFromFile("Textures\\Blocks\\Texture.png"))
    {
        std::cout << "Error!";
    }
    else
    {
        std::cout << "Sucess!";
    }
}
```

I've tried searching for any solutions (including this site) but have not found any.

Comment: Please search this site for your error before posting. In this case, search for `[c++] unresolved external symbol`, and you'll find literally hundreds of hits. If you didn't find them, you didn't search for the error message.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you have a static member in C++, you should define it in your .cpp :

```
static Texture Texture::texture;
```

This is because static members must be defined in exactly one translation unit, in order to not violate the [**One-Definition Rule**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One_Definition_Rule).

---

You can do it at the top of your TextureManager.cpp:

```
#include <SFML\Graphics.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include "TextureManager.h"

using namespace sf;

static Texture Texture::texture; // <-

void TextureManager::Initialize()
{
}
```